The Generalized quadratic Gauss sums
The Generalized quadratic Gauss sums is defined as $$G(a,b,c) = \sum_{n=0}^{c-1}e^{2\pi i \frac{a n^2 + b n}{c}}$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are natural numbers. The generalized quadratic Gauss sums has several properities, which can be found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum.
My confusion is that what the quadratic Gauss sums will be when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and do the above properties still hold when $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

If $a,b$ are not integers, then the summand is not periodic in $n$ with period $c$, so it doesn’t make much sense to truncate the sum at $c-1$. You can still ask what it is, but I doubt it has any nice properties.

I have noticed that the first property: The Gauss sum $G(a,b,c)$ depends only on the residue class of $a$ and $b$ modulo $c$. From my first look, this property appears to still hold for the scenario where $a$ and $b$ are not integers ( $c$ is a natural number). I am not completely certain about this.
